# Code wars challenge

Tags: javascript

https://www.codewars.com/kata/55d5434f269c0c3f1b000058/train/javascript - that is the link for the task :

```
function tripledouble(num1, num2) {
var a = 0;
var b = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < num1.length; i++){
if(true){
    var j = i +1;
    if(num1[i]=== num1[j]){
        return a = 1;
    }else{
        return a = 0;
    }}
}
for ( var x =0; x<num2.length; x++){

if(true){
    var h = x +1;
    if(num1[x]=== num1[h]){
        return   b = 1;
    }else{
        return  b = 0;

}
}

}
return a*b;

}
```

I have 2 questions -

1) What is wrong with my code - like where is my mistake
and Second :
2) Is it possible to solve this task with arr.reduce()?

Comment: Please explain in details, what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: What *is* wrong with your code? This is Stack Overflow. Do you have a question?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* You can't just link to the task on a 3rd party site (though you should cite your sources), you have to explain what you want and what's happening instead in your post.

Comment: So the idea is to check whether any random number in the in the array is equal to the following number. And if that is the case to return 1, if not 0. So for example if num 1 is equal to (1, 2, 3, 3 ,4 ,5 ,5) - i want the function to return 1 - because the 3 is the 3rd number and the following number is again 3. By the way sorry for my very inappropriate topic - i am just new in the community and i believe i will adapt quickly enough

Answer (score 1):

I think where you were running into issues was at the very beginning of your code.  You cannot iterate over numbers.  In the future you will want to always verify the input that is coming in.  A simple console.log(num1, num2) would have been able to illustrate to you that there is an issue with iterating over the inputs.

typeof operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Anyways I had fun doing this.  I hope it helps you out! If you feel like it was helpful or if you think other people will think that it is helpful don't be afraid to hit the upvote button.

```
function tripledouble(num1, num2) {

  const first = [...JSON.stringify(num1).split('')];
  const second = [...JSON.stringify(num2).split('')];

  const triple = first
   .filter((v, k) => v === first[k+1] && v === first[k+2]);

  const double = second
   .filter((v, k) => v === second[k+1]);

  const result = triple
    .filter(trip => double
    .find(dub => dub === trip)) 

  return result.length >= 1 ? 1 : 0;

}
```